# Normalizer of subgroup in $S_5$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Consider $H = \{id, (1 2 3), (1 3 2)\}$ in $S_5$. How many elements are in its normalizer?

Observe that $H$ is generated by $h=(123)$, and $h^{-1}=(132)$, so the calculation boils down to finding how many $g\in S_5$ there are such that $ghg^{-1}=h$ or $ghg^{-1}=h^{-1}$. The former elements are exactly the elements in the centralizer of $h$, which I have found to be $6$, however I am finding it difficult to get anywhere from the latter relation. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with how conjugation affects a permutation, written in cycle notation? For example, if $h=(123)(45)$, then $ghg^{-1} = (g(1)g(2)g(3))(g(4)g(5))$.

Comment: @Nick yes I know that conjugation leaves the cycle type intact and how conjugating with g affects h. Then we know that $(g(1)g(2)g(3))$ can be $(1 2 3)$ or $(132)$. Therefore we are looking for these permutations which include $(4)(5)$ or $(45)$ in their cycles, but I'm having trouble counting how many of these there are.

Comment: In your case, $h=(123)(4)(5)$. So in order to get $(132)(4)(5)$, you need to conjugate by something which either fixes or swaps 4 and 5, and should send 123 to either 132, 321, or 213 (these are just the cyclic permutations of 132). It looks like there are six possibilities.

Comment: The answer is actually $12$: $6$ possibilities for $(4)(5)$ and $6$ for $(45)$

Comment: Do you mean 12 possibilities just to get $h^{-1}$ as the result, or 12 possibilities to get either $h$ or $h^{-1}$?

Comment: Yeah get either $h$ or $h^{-1}$, sorry if this wasn't clear

Comment: I see. I just meant six to get $h^{-1}$, since in your original post, you seem to be fine with finding how many give $h$.